# Need some help with page walking algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree, operating-system

I am writing my own operating system and I want to validate whether dirty bits are set or not. So I want to walk through a certain virtual address range say R! to R2 and walk through pages and check its set or not.I am looking for a good algorithm for doing this. I can treat each page table level as a level of a tree and walk through each level. So I can use DFS or BFS. Is there a better algorithm for doing this ?

Comment: *"I am writing my own operating system and I want to validate whether dirty bits are set or not"* - dirty bits for what?  The page table, for whether or not swapped pages need to be re-flushed?  What does this have to do with a tree?

Comment: Hi The dirty bits are for each page table entry. As far as tree is concerned modern day OSs have multiple levels of page tables which resembles like a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Properties) if you want to check each entry. DFS only requires a stack no deeper than the number of levels in the tree, and page tables are only a few levels deep.

BFS is slower and [requires additional storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Space_complexity). It's generally most useful when the breadth-first property lets you break out early.